# Custom Edit Form for SharePoint list with GridView

Tags: rendering-template

I'm trying go make a custom list form when editing a list item, which should show some associated items from another list. I already fail at making a custom form for editing. I made a new RenderingTemplate and it already shows up when I edit a list item. 
At the moment im adding a new gridview with id GridView1:

```
    <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" Src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OrderControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Shop.CONTROLTEMPLATES.OrderControl" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Shop" TagName="OrderItemsControl" Src="OrderItemsControl.ascx" %>
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="OrderControlTemplate" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id='part1'>
                        <SharePoint:InformationBar ID="InformationBar1" runat="server" />
                        <div id="listFormToolBarTop">
                            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbltop" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                                <template_rightbuttons>
                                    <SharePoint:NextPageButton runat="server"/>
                                    <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>
                                    <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>
                                </template_rightbuttons>
                            </wssuc:ToolBar>
                        </div>
                        <SharePoint:FormToolBar ID="FormToolBar1" runat="server" />
                        <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage ID="ItemValidationFailedMessage1" runat="server" />
                        <table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <SharePoint:ChangeContentType ID="ChangeContentType1" runat="server" />
                            <SharePoint:FolderFormFields ID="FolderFormFields1" runat="server" />
                            <SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server" />

                            <SharePoint:ApprovalStatus ID="ApprovalStatus1" runat="server" />
                            <SharePoint:FormComponent ID="FormComponent1" TemplateName="AttachmentRows" ComponentRequiresPostback="false" runat="server" />
                        </table>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 7px">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server">OrderItems</asp:Label><asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Testbtn" />
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

                                    <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion ID="ItemHiddenVersion1" runat="server" />
                                    <SharePoint:ParentInformationField ID="ParentInformationField1" runat="server" />
                                    <SharePoint:InitContentType ID="InitContentType1" runat="server" />
                                    <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbl" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                                        <template_buttons>
                                    <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo runat="server"/>
                                </template_buttons>
                                        <template_rightbuttons>
                                    <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>
                                    <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>
                                </template_rightbuttons>
                                    </wssuc:ToolBar>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl1" runat="server" ControlId="RelatedItemsPlaceHolder" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload ID="AttachmentUpload1" runat="server" />
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

when I'm entering the Edit-Mode for a Listitem, I get an empty page. Why is that?

I also tried to edit the GridView from the code behind but I wasn't able to get it there when searching by ID.

How can I use the grid view in a custom Edit-Item-Form?

Comment: use jquery SPServices library SPDisplayRelatedInfo http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I found out that if you want to refer to another List, it is best to make a new User Control for this List and then using the Reference Tag:

    <%@ Register TagPrefix="Custom" TagName="OrderItemsControl" Src="OrderItemsControl.ascx" %>

And on the Position where you want to have this content, use:

     <Custom:OrderItemsControl runat="server" />

This lets you view items from another list in the edit-view of another lists list-item-edit-view. I needed it to display the items of a order when editing/viewing the order-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if you want to refer to another List, it is best to make a new User Control for this List and then using the Reference Tag:
`<%@ Register TagPrefix="Custom" TagName="OrderItemsControl" Src="OrderItemsControl.ascx" %>`

And on the Position where you want to have this content, use:
`<Custom:OrderItemsControl runat="server" />`

This lets you view items from another list in the edit-view of another lists list-item-edit-view. I needed it to display the items of a order when editing/viewing the order-item.